# how to make an inline javascript excute every second

Tags: javascript

I have inline javascript which is a clock, but the clock does not refresh which makes it stop on the second that the page loaded. Someone pls help me fix this clock.

```js
function showTime() {
  let date = new Date();
  let h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
  let m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
  let s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
  let session = "AM";

  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  }

  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    session = "PM";
  }

  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  let time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
  document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerHTML = time;
}
setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="MyClockDisplay" class="">clock</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` is what you're after. It will run continuously every time interval until you manually stop it with clearInterval(). For that reason, you should assign a variable to it.

```
let timeInterval = setInterval(showTime, 1000);
// if ever you want to stop or pause the clock, you can use:
// clearInterval(timeInterval)
```

```js
function showTime() {
  let date = new Date();
  let h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
  let m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
  let s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
  let session = "AM";

  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  }

  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    session = "PM";
  }

  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  let time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
  document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerHTML = time;
}
let timeInterval = setInterval(showTime, 1000);
// if ever you want to stop or pause the clock, you can use:
// clearInterval(timeInterval)
```

```html
<div id='MyClockDisplay'></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

`setTimeout` runs only once after a given duration. But `setInterval` will keep on running on given duration. It will only stop if `clearInterval` is called.